# Displayed Jquery variable doesn't change when the Variable Changes

Tags: jquery, variables, checkbox

I use this to check for the nubmer of boxes checked

```
    var CheckedChecks = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

and then I place that result in a long string of HTML. I have alerts set up so I know that the variable is changing. (I'm having trouble pasting in the html but it doesn't really matter...

```
    $(".pt-sel:first").append("HTML CRAP"+ CheckedChecks +"MORE HTML CRAP")
```

All the html is displaying fine and the initial value of 0 for the number of checked boxes is correct however it doesn't update as the variable updates. 
Both the var and the display of the var occur within the same {} set so that isn't the problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Neither of these 2 worked, I'll let you know when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, CheckedChecks only calculates the length once, and then becomes static until the length property is referenced again.

So, if I am correct in understanding the problem, I think you should try this. Forgive me if I don't comprehend the issue.

```
var CheckedChecks = function(){
 return $('input:checkbox:checked').length;
};

$('.pt-sel:first').append('HTML CRAP'+CheckedChecks()+'MORE HTML CRAP');
```

Or just

```
$('.pet-sel:first').append('HTML CRAP'+$('input:checkbox:checked').length+'MORE HTML CRAP');
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable will not update automatically.

You will have to hook into the onchanged event of all the checkboxes to update the text.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
   var CheckedChecks = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
   //cant use append, so put a div at bottom, and fill this.
   $(".pt-sel:first #myDiv").html("HTML CRAP"+ CheckedChecks +"MORE HTML CRAP")
});
```

(This assumes you want to apply to all checkboxes. Give the checkboxes a class if you need to be more specific)